# Is there a context where every vowel makes a valid word?

Tags: vowel

Take, for example, the context N_X. By putting in different vowels, you can get *nex* "murder", *nix* "snow", *nox* "night", *nux* "nut", and *Nyx* "Night (personified)". Unfortunately, there's no word ***nax* to complete the set.

Is there any context where *every* vowel can be swapped in, and create a valid word? (It doesn't have to work for both long and short vowels, or for the foreign sound *Y*, but bonus points if it does.)

Comment: Can you re-phrase that? Can you explain your idea of 'context' which, here, seems to be quite different from most people's? 

Take 'N_X', which is an example, not a context.

When there's no word 'nax' to complete the set, how could that matter at all, let alone present any 'context'??

When there's no '**nax…' what are those '**…' stars for, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin In linguistics, the "context" for a sound is the arrangement of sounds that appear around it. For example, the sound /e/ can appear in the context n\_x, in the word _nex_. The stars indicate a form that does not exist; in historical linguistics, it's common to use one star for a form that isn't attested, but probably did exist, and two stars for a form that probably never existed at all. For example, the word _major_ seems to have come from earlier \*_mag-ior_, but there are no surviving attestations of that earlier form. Meanwhile \*\*_nax_ is simply not a word.

Comment: Really? Where is that written and in any case, why are you trying to force Latin into SE Linguistics?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin It's standard terminology that you can find in most historical linguistics textbooks. I apologize if you find it confusing, but given the upvotes and answers to this question, I don't think the stack in general has an issue with it. If you're worried about the moderators "forcing" things onto the site, I recommend posting about it on [Meta](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com), where other users will see it and weigh in.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin As for why I use this terminology, though: linguistics terminology is generally useful for talking about language, and historical linguistics terminology especially useful for talking about dead languages. The difference between "this is an attested word", "this is a word that's not attested but probably existed", and "this is a word that probably never existed at all" is an important one for talking about Latin vocabulary.

Comment: Good for you and why not express that in SE Linguistics, rather than any specific language, including Latin?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The question is specifically about Latin, not about language in general. Again, if you have concerns about the moderators forcing their views on the Stack, I recommend bringing them up on Meta, which will bring it to more people's attention.

Comment: Yes, the Question is specifically about Latin. Meanwhile, what you're saying is all about language in general…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Latin is a language, so using the tools of linguistics to discuss Latin makes perfect sense. If anything, using the same terminology for all languages makes life easier. I really don't see an issue here. But if you think this is something that needs to be fixed, please bring it up on meta.

Comment: Good for you. Of course the same terminology for all languages makes life easier and so what? If Draconis was asking about some kind of quiz-game, that should have been specified. Otherwise, why not just be more realistic?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I'm sorry, I can't figure out the actual objection here. What specifically are you objecting to in this question?

Comment: @cmw If you must make it so simple, may we go back to that schoolroom in which you first met Latin? What did your earliest teacher have to say about the idea that there might be a context in which every vowel made a valid word?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I don't find answering a question with a question very helpful. This isn't a Socratic experience, or even a classroom, and nuance can get lost in comments.

Comment: @cmw It might be fine to hide behind all or any part of 'I don't find answering a question with a question very helpful. This isn't a Socratic experience, or even a classroom, and nuance can get lost in comments…'

If all your doubts were valid, I'd still see your use of them as constructions to hide behind.

Could you get back to the Question?

Comment: The question is: what is your objection? I legitimately don't understand your objection here. I'm trying to figure it out, but it's not clear.

Comment: Actually, the Question is what could you mean by 'Is there a context where every vowel makes a valid word…'?

If you 'legitimately don't understand…' that, what do you understand?

Does 'every vowel made a valid word' mean 'any change of vowel necessarily changes the meaning of the word' or what else?

Why not Post examples, illustrating your suggestion? A negative example might be 'Veni, vidi, vici' but that could only show what you did not mean…

What examples can you offer, please?

Answer (score 8):

I have a few. The best example is *m_ris*, which has plenty of examples for each vowel (disregarding length), except *meris*, which is only attested twice. You can also switch out the -is for -e, although *mere* is attested just once.

*Corn_* also works, but some of these are more unusual:

corna: neuter plural of *cornum*, 'cornelcherry'
corne: a hill mentioned in Pliny
corni: genitive of *cornum* and *Cornus*
corno: ablative of *cornum*
cornu: nominative of *cornu*

Here are some close calls:

cara, cera, cora, cura (no i)
da, de, di, do (no u)
manes, mines, mones, munes (no e)
nato, nito, noto, nuto (no e)
navis, nevis, nivis, novis (no u)
para, pera, pira, pura (no o)
qua, que, qui, quo (no u)
sano, seno, sino, sono (no u)
tane, tene, tine, tune (no o)
taro, tero, tiro, toro (no u)

Comment: @Asteroides Oops, I wasn't clear. I only meant that it wasn't amply attested. Just twice if I remember right.

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by cmw, you can do **m_rī**:

- **marī**: dative singular of *mās* "male", or dative or ablative singular of *mare* "sea"
- **merī**: masculine/neuter genitive singular or masculine nominative plural of *merus* "pure, mere"
- **mīrī**: masculine/neuter genitive singular or masculine nominative plural of *mīrus* "astonishing, amazing"
- **morī**: infinitive of *morior* "to die" 
  **mōrī**: inflected form of *mōrus* "mulberry tree" or *mōrum* "mulberry fruit", or of *mōrus* "foolish"
- **mūrī**: inflected form of *mūrus* "wall" or of *mūs* "mouse"

Also, for many verbs, appending any of the 5 main vowel letters to the supine stem forms a valid word form. Taking *audīt_* for the verb *audiō* "to hear", we have the following:

- **audīta** and **audītā**: feminine nominative or ablative singular forms of the perfect passive participle *audītus*
- **audīte**: vocative masculine singular of *audītus*, or second-person plural present active imperative
- **audītī**: masculine/neuter genitive singular form or masculine nominative plural form of *audītus*
- **audītō**: masculine/neuter dative or ablative form of *audītus*, or second/third-person singular future active imperative
- **audītū**: the ablative singular of the supine, or of the verbal noun *audītus*

Comment: D'oh! Good call on the supine/PPP. It seems so obvious in retrospect, yet I didn't consider it at all.